# Can someone explain to me this 'counting sentences' php code?

Tags: php, string, count, word-count

I have a task to count sentences without using `str_word_count`, my senior gave it to me but I am not able to understand. Can someone explain it?

I need to understand the variable and how it works.

```
<?php

$sentences = "this book are bigger than encyclopedia";

function countSentences($sentences) {
    $y = "";
    $numberOfSentences = 0;
    $index = 0;

    while($sentences != $y) {
        $y .= $sentences[$index];
        if ($sentences[$index] == " ") {
            $numberOfSentences++;
        }
        $index++;
    }
    $numberOfSentences++;
    return $numberOfSentences;
}

echo countSentences($sentences);

?>
```

The output is

> 6

Comment: If this is actually about counting sentences, then it's broken.

Comment: It counts words not sentences and it does this by walking each character in the string and counting single space characters.

Comment: Hi Hana Ganesa; I'm afraid your question is too broad for this site. Stack overflow is designed for precise questions and answers on identifiable code problems; whereas what you are really asking for as an introduction to basic programming structures. That is out of scope for this site; there are may good textbooks and tutorials available out there, but here is not the place for recommendations I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something very trivial, I'd say.
The task is to count **words** in a *sentence*. A sentence is an string (a sequence of characters) that are letters or white spaces (space, new line, etc.)...

Now, what's a word of the sentence? It is a distinct group of letters that "don't touch" other group of letters; meaning words (group of letters) are separated from each other with white space (let's say just a normal blank space)

So the simplest algorithm to count words consist in:
- $words_count_variable = 0
- go through all the characters, one-by-one
- each time you find a space, it means a new word just ended before that, and you have to increase your $words_count_variable
- lastly, you'll find the end of the string, and that means a word just ended before that, so you'll increase for the last time your $words_count_variable

Take "this is a sentence".

```
We set $words_count_variable = 0;

Your while cycle will analyze:
"t"
"h"
"i"
"s"
" " -> blank space: a word just ended -> $words_count_variable++ (becomes 1)
"i"
"s"
" " -> blank space: a word just ended -> $words_count_variable++ (becomes 2)
"a"
" " -> blank space: a word just ended -> $words_count_variable++ (becomes 3)
"s"
"e"
"n"
...
"n"
"c"
"e"
-> end reached: a word just ended -> $words_count_variable++ (becomes 4)
```

So, 4.
4 words counted.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, it is just counting the number of space in a sentence.

```
<?php

  $sentences = "this book are bigger than encyclopedia";

  function countSentences($sentences) {
    $y = ""; // Temporary variable used to reach all chars in $sentences during the loop
    $numberOfSentences = 0; // Counter of words
    $index = 0; // Array index used for $sentences

    // Reach all chars from $sentences (char by char)
    while($sentences != $y) {
      $y .= $sentences[$index]; // Adding the current char in $y

      // If current char is a space, we increase the counter of word
      if ($sentences[$index] == " "){
        $numberOfSentences++;
      }

      $index++; // Increment the index used with $sentences in order to reach the next char in the next loop round
    }

    $numberOfSentences++; // Additional incrementation to count the last word
    return $numberOfSentences;
  }

  echo countSentences($sentences);

?>
```

Be aware that this function will have wrong results on several case, for example if you have two spaces following, this function will count 2 words instead of one.